# Plot 3D surface in Hydro

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to find how to plot 3D data that represents a surface, over time. It should basically look like a grid surface that moves, in a 3d plot. I know this should be a simple task, does anyone have any ideas?

PS: an equivalent of what I am trying to achieve is like the **surf()** function in MATLAB.

Thank you, everyone.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143991/plot-3d-surface-in-hydro/) by [Haikal Pribadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1779/haikal-pribadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-03-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-03-26**:
Just to clarify: rxplot as well as rqt_plot are both only plotting single numeric values over time. So neither of them will fit your needs.

**Comment by [Haikal Pribadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1779/haikal-pribadi/) on 2014-03-26**:
yep, I realized that after looking into it a little more. That was a bad example. I will edit my question, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can write a C++ or python ROS node that constructs and publishes an rviz marker: http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker . POINTS or TRIANGLE_LIST marker types would probably work.

If you want something more like matlab, but don't want to use matlab for some reason, you could try using the 3d plotting in the matplotlib python package: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Haikal Pribadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1779/haikal-pribadi/) on 2014-03-26**:
Thank you! We're almost there..
RViz seems convenient, but do you know if there's any way I can plot my data to show like this wireframe plot: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#wireframe-plots ?

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-03-26**:
To get that kind of plot in rviz you'll have to write some code. Shouldn't be too hard to write C++ or python to generate a grid of points in the XY plane, evaluate your function to get Z at each point, and make a LINE_LIST rviz Marker that displays the surface. You'll have to write that code though

**Comment by [Haikal Pribadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1779/haikal-pribadi/) on 2014-03-27**:
Thanks jbinney, i've went with RVIZ for now.